# R: splitting long zoo time series into calendar

Tags: r, zoo

I have a several-year length zoo object.

This is a time series of daily quotes (first column : date, second column : quote)

I wish to split this long time series into calendar year subsets, the ultimate goal being to plot those data in a single chart, the horizontal axis of which being one year-length.

(I don't want to convert my source daily data into monthly ones or any other timestep ...).

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way

```
library(quantmod)
getSymbols("SPY", src='yahoo', from='2000-01-01', to='2012-01-01')
SPY <- as.zoo(Ad(SPY))
# Now I have zoo data with a single value for each day (like you say you have)
# Convert it to xts so that I can use xts' split method
mydata <- as.xts(SPY)
# Split data by years.  Give them rownames that are day of year instead of 
# specific dates. cbind data together and plot
ts.plot(do.call(cbind, lapply(split(mydata, 'years'), function(x) {
  zoo(x, 1:NROW(x))
})), col=rainbow(nyears(mydata)))
```

Alternatively,

```
tapply(SPY, format(index(SPY), "%Y"), c)
```

will split by year and does not require converting to `xts`

Comment: thank you for your reply. actually, these are dates but (formatted YYYY-mm-dd) but not days of year.

Comment: anyway, i adapted a bit the code you suggested, and that works well, except i would prefer the months of the year on the horizontal axis instead of integers up to (about) 250.

Comment: I thought you wanted the horizontal axis to be the length of one year?  If so, you have to change the index; if you do not change the index, then you'll have a horizontal axis that is longer than 1 year.

Comment: Here is a variation along somewhat the same lines: `tt <- time(SPY); DF <- data.frame(Date = as.Date(format(tt, "2000-%m-%d")), Year = format(tt, "%Y"), SPY = coredata(SPY)); z <- read.zoo(DF, split = "Year"); plot(z, screen = 1)` or drop the `screen=1` for a multi-panel plot - one panel per year.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck -- That's really handy!